# missing destination file operand when cp

Tags: cp

i tried to use the Linux alias:

```
rm='cp $* ~/dustbin; rm $*'
```

but it reported 'missing destination file operand after ~/dustbin' ,
why didn't cp recognize ~/dustbin as destination ?

Comment: Are you running this in a script or straight on the command line?

Comment: i used it as an alias in my _.profile_ and then i ran it on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use bash?
man bash:

```
There  is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text.  If
arguments are needed, a shell function should be  used  (see  FUNCTIONS
below).
```

Use function, e.g.:

```
rm() { cp $* ~/dustbin; /bin/rm $*; }
```

Comment: thanks, it works. by the way, the `alias rm='echo $*'` does print out the arguments, why didn't _cp_ receive the arguments ?

Comment: `$*` of alias does not receive arguments and seems to disappear. So, `alias rm='echo $*'` is equal to `alias rm=echo`, and `rm a b c` is `echo a b c`.